# Access Enforce Referential Integrity Error: Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types

Tags: ms-access, ms-office, foreign-key-relationship, database-replication, autonumber

In Access 2013, I am trying to link an AutoNumber with the field size set to "Replication ID" to another table with "Enforce Referencial Integrity" enabled.

However, I am unable to find a field type that does not provide a "Relationship must be on the same number of fields with the same data types" error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer.

The Number data type has several options for the size of the field, one of such options is "Replication ID", with the field set as such, I was able to successfully create the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

To create a relationship with *"Enforce referential Integrity"* between two fields, the fields *Data Type* **and** *Field Size* must be the same.
You can have for exapmple two tables you want to join.

**Table Projects (primary key ID):**

```
Field Name        Data Type      Field Size
ID                AutoNumber     Long Integer
```

**Table Tasks (foreign key ProjectID):**

```
Field Name        Data Type      Field Size
ProjectID         Number         Integer
```

Access will let you join these fields, but will not let you check "Enforce referential integrity".